# Why is this numpy array operation so slow?

Tags: python, arrays, matrix, numpy

I am a python beginner and I am trying to average two NumPy 2D arrays with shape of (1024,1024). Doing it like this is quite fast:

```
newImage = (image1 + image2) / 2
```

But now the images have a "mask" that invalidate certain elements if set to zero. That means if one of the elements is zero, the resulting element should also be zero. My trivial solution is:

```
newImage = numpy.zeros( (1024,1024) , dtype=numpy.int16 )

for y in xrange(newImage.shape[0]):
   for x in xrange(newImage.shape[1]):
      val1 = image1[y][x]  
      val2 = image2[y][x]                            
      if val1!=0 and val2!=0:               
         newImage[y][x] = (val1 + val2) / 2
```

But this is really slow. I did not time it, but it seems to be slower by a factor of 100.

I also tried using a lambda operator and "map", but this does not return a NumPy array.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try this:

```
newImage = numpy.where(np.logical_and(image1, image2), (image1 + image2) / 2, 0)
```

Where none of `image1` and `image2` equals zero, take their mean, otherwise zero.

Answer (score 2):

Looping with native Python code is generally much slower than using
built-in tools that use fast C loops. I'm not familiar with NumPy; can
you use `map()` to do a transformation from your two input arrays to
the output? If so, that should be faster.

Answer (score 1):

Explicit `for` loops are very inefficient in Python in general, not only for `numpy` operations. Fortunately, there are faster ways to solve our problem. If memory is not an issue, this solution is quite good:

```
import numpy as np
new_image = np.zeros((1024, 1024), dtype=np.int16)
valid = (image1!=0) & (image2!=0)
new_image[valid] = (image1+image2)[valid]
```

Another solution using masked arrays, which do not create copies of the arrays (they represent views of the original `image1/2`:

```
m1 = np.ma.masked_equal(image1, 0)
m2 = np.ma.masked_equal(image2, 0)
new_image = (m1+m2).filled(0)
```

**Update:** The first solution seems to be 3 times faster than the second for arrays with about 1000 non-zero entries.

Answer (score 0):

numpy array access operation seems slow at best. I can't see any reason for it. You can clearly see it by constructing a simple example:

```
    import numpy
    # numpy version
    def at(s,n):
      t1=time.time()
      a=numpy.zeros(s,dtype=numpy.int32)
      for i in range(n):
        a[i%s]=n
      t2=time.time()
      return t2-t1
    # native version
    def an(s,n):
      t1=time.time()
      a=[(i) for i in range(s)]
      for i in range(n):
        a[i%s]=n
      t2=time.time()
      return t2-t1

    # test
    [at(100000,1000000),an(100000,1000000)]
```

Result: [0.21972250938415527, 0.15950298309326172]